# Абсолютный индекс элемента

Tags: java, html, jsoup, парсер

Здравствуйте. Используя Jsoup для парсинга страничек столкнулся с такой проблемой: На странице присутствует три одинаковых элемента. Например:

```
<span class="c21 c35">Вариант 1</span>
```

Когда я пытаюсь сделать так: doc.allElements.indexOf(element), то получаю индекс только первого элемента, независимо от того, какой передаю на самом деле.
Очень бы хотелось найти альтернативный способ для определения этого самого индекса)

P.S. Индекс использую, чтобы получать другие классы, находящиеся рядом.

Comment: О каком абсолютном индексе элемента может идти речь в структуре дерева?

Comment: Используйте те средства навигации по структуре данных, которые максимально определяют структуру данных. Библиотека Jsoup, например, парсит документ html страницы в DOM структуру (структуру дерева). И для получения ссылок на определенные элементы документа, надо не искать элемент по маске, изображая из себя css, а обращаться к структуре дерева, к node родительского элемента, доходить до листьев (или искомого элемента)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил для себя так: хотя здесь и писали, что нет абсолютного индекса, я все же не готов с этим согласиться. Jsoup и kotlin позволяет сделать так: document.allElements. В итоге получаем коллекцию, элементы которой, естественно, имеют индекс.
т.е.

```
for ((i, element) in document.allElements) {
 //здесь мы находим наш элемент, его индекс будет равен i
}
```

потом к нашему элементу можно без проблем обращаться по индексу.
document.allElements[наш индекс]

Для моих задач решение подходит)